# Assign members of a list to another list

Tags: c#, list, menu, assign

I have 6 doctors listed like this: (one example).

```
ListDoctor.Add(new Medico(01, "Antonio", 555444333, "antonio@gmail.com", "Dermatologista"));
```

And I want to assign to each of these 6 Doctors, 1 member of this list (20 members).

```
ListSickPeople.Add(new Utente(100001, "Pedro", 914754123, "pedro@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
```

This is like an hospital, I want to each Doctor to have Patient assigned but it has to respect the color hierarqy.

This is the color code I used.

```
static ConsoleColor[] colors = { ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.Magenta }; //Ticket Colors.
    static ConsoleColor GetRandomColor()

    {

        return colors[random.Next(colors.Length)];
    }
```

The order of gravity is Magenta, Red, Yellow and Green which I am assigning randomly each time I start my program.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of result you expect - neither doctor has a patients property, nor patient has doctor property

Comment: But to do this do I have necessarly to add a property on each class?

Comment: I just say it's totally unclear what *assign patient to doctor* means and what role colors play here. Correct me if I wrong - you have 20 patients with randomly assigned colors, and you need to assign those patients to 6 doctors. So that patients with magenta colors will be assigned first, then patients with red colors will be assigned to free doctors, or added to queue to doctors which already have magenta patients assigned, etc

Comment: I have to output a List of Doctors treating Patients. But I only have 6 doctors and 20 patients. I need to assign 1 patient to 1 doctor but respecting color hierarqy. If there are 3 Magentas, all of them have priority. Next are Reds, and so on.

Comment: Each doctor has list of patients, or each doctor has one patient?

Comment: Are you allowed to order the color enum any way you like or do they have to be in that order?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Exactly. Assign to each Doctor one of these 20 Patient and put the remaining ones on a queue.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Not sure what you are asking but I have total permissions to modify the code so I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework question, so I'm going to write in pseudocode ;)

First, order your colors from highest priority to lowest so that you can loop over them in priority order e.g.

```
colors = { Magenta, Red, Yellow, Green }
```

As Sergey suggested, add a Doctor property to the Patient object to record which doctor is assigned, and a Patient property to the Doctor object.

Next, loop over the colors with an inner loop that loops over the patients. For each patient, check if its priority is the current color and assign it one of the free doctors. To find a free doctor, loop over the doctors until you find one that has no patient. e.g.

```
foreach (var color in colors)
    foreach (var patient in ListSickPeople)
        if (patient.Color == color)
        {
            foreach (var doctor in ListDoctor)
            {
                if (doctor.Patient == null)
                    patient.Doctor = doctor
                    doctor.Patient = patient
            }
            if (patient.Doctor == null) // went through all doctors and they're all assigned, so add patient to queue
                queue.Add(patient)
        }
```

You could make it detect when all the doctors have been assigned with a counter or by having a second list of available doctors from which you can remove. Once you detect that doctors are all assigned, quit the top loop.

Using LINQ would make it more readable. But this should give the general idea.

Comment: If you really don't want to add properties to the Doctor and Patient classes then you'll need another way to record their associations, like a class that has Doctor and Patient properties or their IDs. You then have to loop through the table looking for the doctor or patient and ensure you don't assign doctors more than once. Having the properties on the classes themselves clarifies and enforces the one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your sugestion, gonna give it a try and report in. I can add those properties, seems like the easier way to do it. Im just confused where do I add the line with the colors = { Magenta, Red, Yellow, Green }.

Comment: You could rearrange your static ConsoleColor[] colors to do this, or create an enum with those colors.

Comment: Ok, I will try to edit the static ConsoleColor and report the results. Thanks again!

Comment: Is this the correct way to edit the color properties?

Comment: static colors = { Magenta, Red, Yellow, Green }
            static colors GetRandomColor()
            {
            
                return colors[random.Next(colors.Length)];
            }

Answer (score 1):

Your current list of colors does not show the priority of colors - they are just in random order. If you still want to use ConsoleColors (see notes below), then you should at least define the priority of each color by their order:

```
static ConsoleColor[] ticketPriorities = { // give descriptive name to list of priorities
      ConsoleColor.Green, 
      ConsoleColor.Yellow,
      ConsoleColor.Red,
      ConsoleColor.Magenta
    };
```

All you have to do now is sort patients by priority and assign them to doctors. It's can be done via index of the patient in the ordered patient's list. Everything is done by single LINQ query:

```
var assignments = ListSickPeople
     .OrderByDescending(p => ticketPriorities.IndexOf(p.Priority))
     .Select((patient,index) => 
        new {
           Patient = patient,
           Doctor = ListDoctor[index % ListDoctor.Count]
        });
```

That will give you ordered pairs of patient-doctor assignments.

Note - it's not good to use `ConsoleColor` which is a UI thing in your business rules. You still can use color names as the priority, but that should be a domain concept of patient priority rather than a color supported by the system console. Though it's better to use names which mean priority rather than a design of tickets:

```
public enum TicketPriority
{
    Low,     // Green
    Normal,  // Yellow
    High,    // Red
    Top      // Magenta
}
```

Another problem with `ConsoleColor` is that you can assign any console color to patients priority - e.g. `White` or `Black`.

And one more problem with such predefined assignment is that every visit to the doctor should take exactly same time (e.g. 15 minutes). Otherwise, patients with lower priorities can visit their doctors before some high-priority patients. To fix that you should create a pool of doctors which will take next patient in ordered patient's queue (`Queue<T>`) as soon as they get free.

Comment: Your sugestion is good but this is part of a project that has rules. One of these rules is using colors to assign priorities. It would be easier using your sugestion but I can't do that.

Comment: @Dany4k my answer is not about renaming colors. it's just a suggestion which you can skip